# Can a Service starts several Tasks?

Tags: javafx, multitasking

I need to use a `Service` which starts a `Task` more than once (= the same `Service` must run several parallelised `Task`). I read the JavaFX documentation, and they seem to say that a `Service` can run only one `Task` at once.

So if I call twice `start` with my `Service` object, the first `Task` returned by its `createTask` method would be stopped, as if I used `restart` after the first `start`.

However, that's not clear. As I told you, the documentation *seems* to tell that.
Indeed :

> A Service creates and manages a Task that performs the work on the background thread.

Note that I could think they also say that a `Service` can have several `Task` started at the same time. Indeed :

> a Service can be constructed declaratively and restarted on demand.

**My question is** : if I use N `start` in a row, will N `Tasks` be created AND KEEP EACH RUNNING ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "If I use N start in a row, will N Tasks be created AND KEEP EACH RUNNING ?

In short, no.

> "If I call `start` twice with my `Service` object..."

From the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html#start--):

> `public void start()`
>
> Starts this Service. The Service must be in the READY state to succeed in this call.

So if you call `start()` a second time without previously calling [`reset()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html#reset--), you will just get an exception. You can only call `reset()` if the `Service` is not in a `RUNNING` or `SCHEDULED` state. You can call `restart()`, which will have the effect of *first canceling any current task*, and then restarting the service. (This is what is meant by the documentation that says the "service can be restarted on demand".)

The net result of this is that a service cannot have two currently running tasks at the same time, since there is no sequence of calls that can get to that situation without throwing an `IllegalStateException`.

If you want multiple tasks running at once, simply create them yourself and submit them to an executor (or run each in its own thread, but an executor is preferred):

```
private final Executor exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(runnable -> {
    Thread t = new Thread(runnable);
    t.setDaemon(true);
    return t ;
});

// ...

private void launchTask() {

    Task<MyDataType> task = new Task<MyDataType>(){
        @Override
        protected Something call() {
            // do work...
            return new MyDataType(...);
        }
    };
    task.setOnSucceeded(e -> { /* update UI ... */ });
    task.setOnFailed(e -> { /* handle error ... */ });
    exec.execute(task);

}
```

Comment: Than you ! Do you know if I can make the JavaFX Application Thread wait for the Service's state "SUCCEEDED" ? It will allow me to run several tasks with an only thread when this state would be reached (I know : there wouldn't be parallelism... except between the last task and the JavaFX Application Thread).

Comment: Okay ; the JFX doc indicates that an Executor can be added to a Service. Do you think I can combine my Service + its Task + the Executor which will make use of the latter ? (I would want to keep my Service in fact)

Comment: I am totally lost as to what you are trying to achieve at this point. If you want the tasks to run in parallel, you can't manage them with a `Service` (with or without an `Executor`, which is just an implementation detail of the service). If you don't want them to run in parallel, why not just make them into a single runnable (or single task)? If you want them in parallel and want to know when they are all complete, use a [`CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) in a separate thread.

Comment: In fact, what I really want to do is indeed to run several tasks at once. I didn't express myself properly. Well, I just have my JavaFX Application Thread that launches N `Task` using a `Service` and I would want to launch all of them in parallelism. You told me to make use of an `Executor` (a `CountDownLatch` wouldn't be correct because as you told me, the JFXAPP-Thread can't wait). Thus, I'm going to use `Executor`. In the code you posted with the `Executor`, I didn't find the link between the `Task` and the `Executor` ?

Comment: "I didn't find the link between the `Task` and the `Executor`."  The last line of code: `exec.execute(task)`

Comment: Ah yes sorry... What is the interest of the `Service` ? It can executes a single `Task`, while an `Executor` can executes several. You told me it's a technical implementation detail.

Comment: @Lern-X The "do something when all the tasks have finished" (assuming I understood correctly that that's what you want to do) sounds like a different question, though I already have you a way in a previous comment (wait for a countdown latch *on a separate thread*).

Comment: No, I didn't express myself properly : when these tasks have finished, there is nothing to do in particular.

Comment: So what are you actually asking in all these comments then? What does 'Do you know if I can make the JavaFX Application Thread wait for the Service's state "SUCCEEDED" ? It will allow me to run several tasks with an only thread when this state would be reached' mean?

Comment: And I said the particular executor that the service uses is (essentially) an implementation detail *of the service*. I.e. changing the executor will not change the contract of the service; it can still only execute one task at a time.

Comment: I asked if the JFXApp-Thread could wait for the `Service`'s state `SUCCEEDED` because it would have allow me to avoid the `Executor` , even if there was only one parallelism (between the last `Task` and the JFXApp-Thread). But in fact, the `Executor` is very simple to use. However, I'm encountering a problem with it, wider than in this question. I don't think it would be ok to edit the latter, thus I will certainly create a new one :)