# JavaFX GUI freezes | Usage of multiple tasks

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, responsive-design, java.util.concurrent

I can't update/reset the text in button or update gui info. The GUI freezes every time. I tried all option from stackoverflow, nothing helps...

Can you help me? The JavaFX Thread (Platform.runLater) will be the last to be called and the button text will be changed on the end of process/programm.
The following threads are running at the end of the createTasks method:

**---------------------------------------

1 Name: main; Priority: 1; Thread-Group: java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=main,maxpri=10]

---

2 Name: Reference Handler; Priority: 10; Thread-Group: java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=system,maxpri=10]

---

3 Name: JavaFX Application Thread; Priority: 5; Thread-Group: java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=main,maxpri=10]

---

4 Name: Cleaner-0; Priority: 8; Thread-Group: java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=InnocuousThreadGroup,maxpri=10]

---

5 Name: Notification Thread; Priority: 9; Thread-Group: java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=system,maxpri=10]

---

6 Name: Thread-2; Priority: 7; Thread-Group: java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=main,maxpri=10]

---

7 Name: Signal Dispatcher; Priority: 9; Thread-Group: java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=system,maxpri=10]

---

8 Name: Prism Font Disposer; Priority: 10; Thread-Group: java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=system,maxpri=10]

---

9 Name: InvokeLaterDispatcher; Priority: 4; Thread-Group: java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=main,maxpri=10]

---

10 Name: Finalizer; Priority: 8; Thread-Group: java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=system,maxpri=10]

---

11 Name: QuantumRenderer-0; Priority: 3; Thread-Group: java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=main,maxpri=10]

---

12 Name: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13; Priority: 5; Thread-Group: null

---

13 Name: Common-Cleaner; Priority: 8; Thread-Group: java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=InnocuousThreadGroup,maxpri=10]

---

14 Name: Attach Listener; Priority: 5; Thread-Group: java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=system,maxpri=10]

---

15 Name: Monitor Ctrl-Break; Priority: 2; Thread-Group: java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=main,maxpri=10]

---

16 Name: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5; Priority: 5; Thread-Group: null

---

17 Name: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-7; Priority: 5; Thread-Group: null

---

18 Name: Java2D Disposer; Priority: 10; Thread-Group: java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=system,maxpri=10]

---

19 Name: JavaFX-Launcher; Priority: 6; Thread-Group: java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=main,maxpri=10]

---

20 Name: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-15; Priority: 5; Thread-Group: null
**

```
    public class CreateTabController {

    public Button btnStart;
    public Button btnStopCreating;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listOfCompletelyProtocols = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listOfNotCompletelyProtocols = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listOfNoTestProtocols = new ArrayList<>();

    private HashSet<String> pathsToAllFiles;


public class CustomService extends Service<Map<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>> {

            private int startIndex;
            private int endIndex;
            private String[] allPaths;
            private ArrayList<String> searchParams;
            private String searchType;
            private boolean separatelyCreating;

            public CustomService(int startIndex, int endIndex, String[] allPaths, ArrayList<String> searchParams, String searchType, boolean separatelyCreating) {
                this.startIndex = startIndex;
                this.endIndex = endIndex;
                this.allPaths = allPaths;
                this.searchParams = searchParams;
                this.searchType = searchType;
                this.separatelyCreating = separatelyCreating;
            }

            @Override
            protected Task<Map<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>> createTask() {

                Task<Map<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>> task = new Task<>() {

                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> call() throws Exception {

                        ImportList importList =
                                new ImportList(startIndex, endIndex, allPaths, searchParams, searchType, separatelyCreating);

                        return importList.getExcelLists();

                    }

                };

                task.setOnRunning(finishEvent-> {

                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            btnStart.setText("läuft...");
                        }

                    });

                });

                return task;
            }


        }

        public Map<String,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> createTasks(HashSet<String> pathsToAllFiles, ArrayList<String> searchParams, String searchType, boolean separatelyCreating) throws InterruptedException {

            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listOfCompletelyProtocols = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listOfNotCompletelyProtocols = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listOfNoTestProtocols = new ArrayList<>();

            String[] allPaths = new String[pathsToAllFiles.size()];
            pathsToAllFiles.toArray(allPaths);
            HashSet<String[]> indexes = CustomTools.getStartEndIndexesByCores(allPaths);



            int processorsNum = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();

            ExecutorService exec = Executors.newWorkStealingPool(processorsNum);

            List<Task<Map<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

            for (String[] indexPair : indexes) {

                int startIndex = Integer.parseInt(indexPair[0]);
                int endIndex = Integer.parseInt(indexPair[1]);

                CreateTabController.CustomService service = new CreateTabController.CustomService(startIndex, endIndex, allPaths, searchParams, searchType, separatelyCreating);
                tasks.add(service.createTask());

                service.setExecutor(exec);
                service.start();
            }

            tasks.forEach(exec::execute);

            Map<String,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> allProcessedPDFs = new HashMap<>();

            for (int j = 0; j < tasks.size(); j++) {

                Task<Map<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>> futureTask = tasks.get(j);
                try {

                    allProcessedPDFs = futureTask.get();

                    listOfNoTestProtocols.addAll(allProcessedPDFs.get("noTestingProtocols"));
                    listOfCompletelyProtocols.addAll(allProcessedPDFs.get("completelyProtocols"));
                    listOfNotCompletelyProtocols.addAll(allProcessedPDFs.get("notCompletelyProtocols"));

                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            allProcessedPDFs.clear();

            allProcessedPDFs.put("noTestingProtocols", listOfNoTestProtocols);
            allProcessedPDFs.put("completelyProtocols", listOfCompletelyProtocols);
            allProcessedPDFs.put("notCompletelyProtocols", listOfNotCompletelyProtocols);

            exec.shutdown();

            return allProcessedPDFs;
        }
        
    }
    
    
package resources;

import com.itextpdf.text.io.FileChannelRandomAccessSource;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor;
import db.DB;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocumentCatalog;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDAcroForm;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDField;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import custom_utils.CustomLogging;

public class ImportList {

    private String filePath;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> importableData = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> notImportableData = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> noTestingProtocols = new ArrayList<>();

    private int startIndex;
    private int endIndex;
    private String[] allPaths;
    private ArrayList<String> searchParams;
    private String searchType;
    private boolean separatelyCreating;

    public ImportList(int startIndex, int endIndex, String[] allPaths, ArrayList<String> searchParams, String searchType, boolean separatelyCreating) {
        this.startIndex = startIndex;
        this.endIndex = endIndex;
        this.allPaths = allPaths;
        this.searchParams = searchParams;
        this.searchType = searchType;
        this.separatelyCreating = separatelyCreating;
    }
    
    public Map<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> getExcelLists() throws Exception {
        return startCreating(startIndex, endIndex, allPaths, searchParams, searchType, separatelyCreating);
    }
    
     private Map<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> startCreating(int startIndex, int endIndex,
                       String[] allPaths, ArrayList<String> searchParams,
                       String searchType, boolean separatelyCreating)
    {


        Map<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> allProcessedPDFs = new HashMap<>();

        for (int j = startIndex; j < endIndex; j++) {

            String path = allPaths[j];

            try {
                if (Files.size(Paths.get(path)) < 10) {
                    break;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            PDDocument doc = null;
            PdfReader readerPdf = null;
            RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = null;
            RandomAccessFileOrArray randomAccessFileOrArray = null;
            FileChannelRandomAccessSource fileChannelRandomAccessSource = null;

            try {

                randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(new File(path), "r");
                fileChannelRandomAccessSource = new FileChannelRandomAccessSource(randomAccessFile.getChannel());
                randomAccessFileOrArray = new RandomAccessFileOrArray(fileChannelRandomAccessSource);
                readerPdf = new PdfReader(randomAccessFileOrArray, null);

                int pageNumbers = readerPdf.getNumberOfPages();
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                for (int i = 1; i <= pageNumbers; i++) {
                    String text= PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(readerPdf, i);
                    stringBuilder.append(text);
                }

                String parsedText = stringBuilder.toString();
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+");
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(parsedText);
                boolean isSearchable = matcher.find();

                if (isSearchable) {

                    File file = new File(path);
                    doc = PDDocument.load(file);
                    List<PDField> fields = null;

                    boolean containsSearchParam = false;
                    PDAcroForm form = null;
                    PDDocumentCatalog pdDocumentCatalog = doc.getDocumentCatalog();

                    if (pdDocumentCatalog != null) {
                        form = pdDocumentCatalog.getAcroForm();
                        if (form != null) {
                            fields = form.getFields();
                        }
                    }

                    if (!separatelyCreating) {

                        for (String searchParam : searchParams) {
                            if (searchParam.length() < 2) {
                                break;
                            }

                            if (searchType.equals(Consts.SEARCH_TYPE_CONTAINS)) {
                                if (StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(parsedText, searchParam)) {
                                    createTechnicalTestData(parsedText, path);
                                }
                            }

                            if (searchType.equals(Consts.SEARCH_TYPE_EQUALS)) {
                                if (isEqual(parsedText, searchParam)) {
                                    createTechnicalTestData(parsedText, path);
                                }
                            }


                            if (fields != null) {

                                for (PDField field : fields) {
                                    if (searchParam.equals(field.getValueAsString())) {
                                        containsSearchParam = true;
                                    }
                                }

                                if (containsSearchParam) {
                                    findTestingDataFromForms(fields, parsedText, path);
                                }

                            }

                        }

                    } else {

                        createTechnicalTestData(parsedText, path);

                        if (fields != null) {
                            findTestingDataFromForms(fields, parsedText, path);
                        }
                    }

                }

                if (doc != null) {
                    doc.close();
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {

                assert randomAccessFileOrArray != null;
                try {
                    randomAccessFileOrArray.close();
                    fileChannelRandomAccessSource.close();
                    randomAccessFile.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }


        }

        if (this.noTestingProtocols != null) {
            allProcessedPDFs.put("noTestingProtocols", this.noTestingProtocols);
        }

        if (this.importableData != null) {
            allProcessedPDFs.put("completelyProtocols", this.importableData);
        }

        if (this.notImportableData != null) {
            allProcessedPDFs.put("notCompletelyProtocols", this.notImportableData);
        }

        return allProcessedPDFs;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is ImportListTask?

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: See [can a service start several tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39859697/can-a-service-starts-several-tasks) -> the answer is “no”.

Comment: I think you are understanding a service. It manages task creation and execution. It creates and runs a single task in its executor when it is started. You can restart it and do it again. It doesn’t create and run multiple simultaneous tasks. You should not separately create, run and manage tasks which the service is handling, if you are going to do that, you don’t need a service at all (and that might be fine, there is a good chance that using a service is not the best way to solve your problem.

Comment: @jewelsea, thanks for your  replies!

I completed the code and renamed "Import List Task".

I want to create several threads (tasks), and run them at the same time and also have the option of being able to stop all of these threads with a click of the mouse. After starting, the text in the button must be changed ("Running") and after completion or interruption, the text "Create".

Comment: @jewelsea, I did exactly the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39859697/can-a-service-starts-several-tasks as described here. Unfortunately that didn't help. 

I understand the meaning and difference between task and service. I understand that GUI can only be updated through JavaFX thread. But this run-later thread is executed at the very end. So the thread ends up at the end of the queue.

Comment: I'd look at a `Task` that manages a `CountDownLatch`; examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjavafx%5d%20Task%20CountDownLatch) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20CountDownLatch).

Comment: You have quite a few errors in your code. It would take some time to fix them. One error is calling futureTask.get() on the JavaFX app thread. That is a blocking api which is going to freeze all JavaFX processing  and event handling until the task completes.  Instead, [get the value](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Worker.html#getValue()) in [an onSuccess](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#onSucceededProperty) event handler.